# how to extract multiple integer from string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my url. I need to extract both 4 and 2 separately for the purpose of searching. These two integer, `one is category id` and other is `sub category id`

```
params[:id].scan(/\d+$/).first
```

using the above scan i can get `4` but how can i get more than one integers

```
my-url-for-test-4-2
```

I have created a helper method

```
  def string_to_int(param,key)
    param.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).key
  end
```

And i tried it from my controller like this

```
id = string_to_int(params[:id],'first')
```

But getting error as

```
undefined method `key' for [4, 2]:Array
```

Why it is not acception.

Comment: You probably mean `.send(key)` (call method with name of passed argument) instead of calling the method `key()`.

Comment: Careful about simply scanning for numerical substrings. That will return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` if you have the URL segment `random1-2string-3-4-5`.

Comment: @kristinalim How can i overcome this kind of complexity then

Comment: Please see my answer. It includes doing matching at the end of the line (`$`), including hyphens in the regex (another separator shouldn't work), and scanning out the last two decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params[:id].scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer lies in your question
`params[:id].scan(/\d/)` will result in array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `first` or `last` as `key` :

```
   def string_to_int(param,key)
     param[:id].scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).send(key)
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match against the last two numerical parts (separated by hyphens) in your `:id` parameter:

```
string = params[:id].to_s
ids = string.scan(/-(\d+)-(\d+)$/)[0] # .try(:map, &:to_i)
```

**Update:**

Here's a not-too-edge case that would be handled well:

```
a = "random1-2string-3-4-5"
a.scan(/-(\d+)-(\d+)$/)                        # => [["4", "5"]]
a.scan(/-(\d+)-(\d+)$/)[0]                     # => ["4", "5"]
a.scan(/-(\d+)-(\d+)$/)[0].try(:map, &:to_i)   # => [4, 5]
```